# that’s/that was one of the worst experiences

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

I'd like to know whether "that's" should have been replaced by "that was" in the following. The experience took place in the past.

> I tried Mary's muffins last Friday, and that’s one of the worst experiences in my life.

Comment: I would use _that was_.

Answer (score 1):

"That's" is a contraction of "that **is**".

So, your question is really about the difference between "that *is*" and "that *was*".

- "That *was* a bad experience" would mean you were referring to a past experience that happened.
- "That *is* a bad experience" would mean you were referring to something you experienced, but can/may be experienced by anyone else at any time.

It is clear from the wider context of your example that the first person is talking about a past experience *in their life*, and saying it is your worst to date. For that reason, "that **was**" is the correct choice.